# Que tipo de dados usar para ID da venda?

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tipagem

Tenho uma aplicação Windows Forms desenvolvida em C# e com banco de dados SQL.

Uma das funções do sistema é realizar VENDA para diversas EMPRESAS diferente e em diversos PDV (ponto de venda) diferente, porem, utilizando uma única base de dados. Utilizo ID para controlar a venda ele é `bigint AUTO_INCREMENT` no banco de dados.

Problema: A empresa 1 faz a venda 1, 3, e 5 a empresa 2 faz a venda 2, 4, 6 o cliente acha que o sistema está errado pois, não está seguindo uma ordem sequencial de venda.

Pensei então em colocar Cód. Empresa + Numero da venda.

Porém, a empresa é gravada na mesma tabela de cliente sendo assim posso facilmente uma empresa com o código 9000 e posso ter uma venda com o código 10000 tenho receio de então esse campo estore. Que tipo de dados eu poderia usar para prevenir isso?

Problema 2: Tenho uma empresa cadastrada 1 e 11 o sistema pode se perde ao realizar a venda quando a empresa 1 fizer a venda 11 ou quando a empresa 11 fizer a venda 1.

De que forma eu poderia resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Dados diferentes

O problema é que está misturando algo interno do sistema com algo externo ao sistema. Até é possível fazer isso, mas a aplicação tem que funcionar tratando isso.

O mais correto parecer ser fazer o que está fazendo para seu controle interno, então tem um `ID` auto incrementado pelo banco de dados. Provavelmente um `BIGINT` é grande demais para o que precisa, mas pode deixar se achar que deve.

Isso é chamado de [chave substituta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101) e é o mais comum de se fazer.

Para mostrar para o usuário haverá um outro controle de numeração sequencial. Precisa ter uma tabela de controle disso por empresa e precisa acessar e incrementar em operação atômica para não criar duplicidade.

## Chave composta

Se não quiser usar uma chave substituta, use o `ID` da empresa em uma coluna e o `ID` da venda em outra coluna e faça a chave primária da tabela ser composta pelas duas colunas juntas. Assim poderá usar um identificador único que não repete que serve para uso interno e atende ao requisito externo.

Espero que um requisito futuro não crie problemas em usar isso.

## Chave única

Ainda pode fazer uma coluna com os dois `ID`s, mas aí eu acho que seria melhor usar um tipo `CHAR`. Não faz sentido juntar dois números da forma que está pensando. Usar um texto não é ideal, mas criar um número juntando algarismos é completamente errado. Coloquei como alternativa, mas não é uma boa solução no geral. Só não descarto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bigown, caso eu use a chave composta eu não terei esse problema: Tenho uma empresa cadastrada 1 e 11 o sistema pode se perde ao realizar a venda quando a empresa 1 fizer a venda 11 ou quando a empresa 11 fizer a venda 1.

Comment: Não, isso não corre, código da empresa é uma coisa, código da venda é outra. Se fez e ocorreu, fez algo errado.

Comment: @bigown está certo. Isso vai ocorrer se fizer somas de inteiros, por exemplo 11 + 1 = 12 e 1 + 11 = 12, porém se concatenar com string fica  1 & 11 = 111 e 111 & 1 = 1111. Olhe meu exemplo na minha resposta.

Comment: @Murilo mas estou falando de chave composta, nem soma números, nem concatena textos. A concatenação ocorreria na terceira opção que coloquei e daria certo também.

Comment: @bigown, como eu faço isso "chave substituta e é o mais comum de se fazer.
Para mostrar para o usuário haverá um outro controle de numeração sequencial. Precisa ter uma tabela de controle disso por empresa e precisa acessar e incrementar em operação atômica para não criar duplicidade."

Comment: @Lilloh É um processo que envolve várias partes do código, não é fácil colocar em uma resposta, pior ainda em um comentário. A resposta do cantoni mostra uma parte disto, apesar de estar em Groovy e não sei se precisa fazer tudo aquilo. Pense que tem dois dados. Um dele ´o `ID` que acho que sabe como lidar, ele é chave primária, seu sistema trabalha com ele. O outro é um dado como outro qualquer que mostra para o usuário. Na verdade são duas colunas, uma delas é a empresa. Acho que é tranquilo fazer isso. A outra é um código sequencial controlado por você. Há uma sequência para cada empresa.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o melhor seja voce usar uma chave primaria gerada pelo proprio SQL ou uma GUID do C# para salvar no banco e adicionar duas colunas, uma o codigo da empresa e outra o numero sequencial da venda, assim quando fizer uma nova venda, a chave nunca vai ser o problema e voce verifica qual foi a ultima venda da empresa e incrementa o numero sequencial.
Como o numero da empresa e o cupom sao colunas separadas acho que voce nao deve ter o segundo problema tambem, ja que a empresa voce pode pegar do usuario logado ou digitar em um campo separado.

Caso nao queira criar as colunas ou tabelas individuas para cada empresa, voce tambem pode usar uma string como chave, colocando um separador entre a empresa e o numero da venda "empresa-venda" depois separando na aplicacao.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente o bigint é um campo muito grande, é difícil estourar, tem que ter muitas vendas mesmo com o código da empresa 9000.

**bigint**: -2^63 (-9.223.372.036.854.775.808) a 2^63-1 (9.223.372.036.854.775.807)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187745.aspx

Você poderia criar uma nova coluna para o número da venda. Mantenha a chave primária como autoincremento do banco de dados, porém você faz o incremento manual do número da venda fazendo um `Max` + 1, exiba o número da venda para o cliente, não o código.

Mesmo que você utilizasse uma `sequence` você não conseguiria as vendas 11 12 13 14 para a empresa 1, seria necessário uma sequence para cada empresa.

Você poderia fazer uma `trigger` que irá gerar o código da venda, gerando o código = código da empresa + qtde de vendas dessa empresa, seus códigos ficariam assim:

Empresa 9000: 90001, 90002, 90003 ,90004, 9000125

Empresa 11: 11, 12, 13, 14, 1125

```
CREATE TRIGGER  triggerInsertVenda ON tbVenda
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS

SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM inserted
DECLARE @codEmpresa int = (SELECT codempresa FROM inserted)
DECLARE @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbVenda WHERE codEmpresa = @codEmpresa)

UPDATE #tmp SET codigo = convert(int, convert(varchar, @codEmpresa) + convert(varchar, @count + 1))


INSERT INTO tbVenda SELECT * FROM #tmp;
```

Comment: Murilo, na verdade eu falei errado eu tenho uma tabela Pessoa ela é relacionada a Cliente, Fornecedor, Funcionário, Profissional e Empresa. A tabela Pessoa é a principal ontem tem as informações que são comum a todos.

Comment: O meu medo de estourar e que o SQL 2012 tem um bug em determinados momentos ele se perder no autoincremento jogando um numero lá na frente. Porem caso eu utilize a solução que você passou, pode ser que ele não estore.

Comment: Ok. Dei o exemplo de como tratar com a trigger.

Comment: @Lilloh, você teria uma referencia sobre esse bug do SQL Server? Gostaria de ler a respeito. Murilo, a solução da Trigger resolve, mas ter que contar os registros da tbVenda a cada venda parece não ser algo bom, principalmente levando em consideração o volume de vendas que pode ocorrer.

Comment: A contagem é instantânea, não tem efeito significante, ainda mais se fizer count(codigo) que é PK. Volume alto seria algo acima de milhões de registros. Esse erro de pular sequência no SQL Server existe no 2012. Já passei por isso. No stackoverflow em inglês tem tópicos sobre isso.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database

Comment: @cantoni o link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d256650-0e94-4d0f-8b52-0ba6e1903215/primary-key-auto-incrementing-by-1000-instead-of-1?forum=transactsql                  

Veja aqui tambem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162648/sql-server-2012-column-identity-increment-jumping-from-6-to-1000-on-7th-entry

Comment: Puxa, um bug vergonhoso. @Murilo, embora o desempenho da soluçao de contagem dependa do número de registros, eu ainda tenho restrições a ela, exatamente porque pelo descrito, me parece que haverá bastante transação (em períodos curtos de tempo), acontecendo nessa tabela, parecem haver vários PDVs. Talvez uma solução que combine a trigger com o que postei na minha resposta tenha um melhor desempenho, ou seja, a cada INSERT na tbVenda a trigger faria uma consulta na SEQUENCIA atual da tabela EMPRESA, incrementaria, gravaria o valor no SEQ_VENDA da tbVenda e depois atualizaria a EMPRESA.

Answer (score 2):

Se o sequencial da venda é algo importante para o usuário, então uma opção viável e não muito complexa é criar um campo na tabela EMPRESA que armazenará em qual sequência se encontra a venda da respectiva empresa.

Caso você opte por esse caminho, então é importante incrementar esse campo de uma maneira que apenas um processo do SQL Server possa alterá-lo por vez. Para isso, você pode fazer da maneira abaixo. O exemplo está na linguagem Groovy, mas é facilmente adaptado para qualquer outra. O importante não é a linguagem, mas os SQLs executados para garantir que apenas um processo do SQL Server possa alterar o campo SEQUENCIA por vez (Retirei isso de um sistema em que faço exatamente isso).

```
def incrementaSequencia(empresaId) {
      sql.execute("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")
      sql.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
      def rs = sql.rows("SELECT SEQUENCIA FROM EMPRESA WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE EMPRESA_ID = :empresaId",[empresaId:empresaId])
      def sequencia = (int)rs.first().SEQUENCIA + 1
      sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE EMPRESA SET SEQUENCIA = " + sequencia + " WHERE EMPRESA_ID = :empresaId",[empresaId:empresaId])
      sql.execute("COMMIT")
      return sequencia
}
```

Note que nesse exemplo eu preciso da sequencia gerada no meu programa, por isso eu executo o SELECT nas instruções acima. Dependendo do caso, basta apenas incrementar o campo com um UPDATE. Algo assim:

```
      sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE EMPRESA SET SEQUENCIA = SEQUENCIA + 1 WHERE EMPRESA_ID = :empresaId",[empresaId:empresaId])
```

Agora basta criar um campo SEQ_VENDA na tabela VENDA e guardar o valor gerado, ou seja, a cada venda você chama a rotina que gera o ID e guarda esse valor no campo SEQ_VENDA.

Sobre o tipo de campo, eu uso sempre `bigint` para IDs numéricos.

Comment: Basicamente eu tenho uma campo na tabela de empresa que grava a ultima venda realizada correto?

Na tabela de Venda eu crio uma coluna Seq_Venda e toda venda que eu fizer eu somo + 1 no codigo da ultima venda realizada.

Depois disse eu sou um update na empresa somando +1 na ultima venda. Seria isso???

Comment: Isso. Você tem um campo na tabela EMPRESA que guarda a sequencia da ultima venda (vamos chama-lo de SEQUENCIA). Esse é o campo que deve ser incrementado. O valor desse campo é o que será utilizado na tabela VENDA, em um campo que eu denominei SEQ_VENDA.

Comment: Entendi então dessa forma eu posso ter N vendas com o código 1.

Comment: Tem como eu fazer um bloqueio no SQL para que a empresa 1 tenha apenas uma venda código 1?

Comment: Sim. A sequencia é por empresa. Portanto, pode ter sequencia repetida sim (mas sempre em empresa diferente). Se vc quer que o sequencial seja unico, então você precisa de um contador global e não por empresa. Porém, você vai cair no mesmo problema, das vendas não estarem em sequencia.

Comment: Esse controle a sequencia pode ser repetida mas em empresa diferente eu tenho que fazer na aplicação correto?

Comment: Como você sabe a EMPRESA para qual a venda está sendo feita, basta chamar essa rotina antes de gravar a venda, obtendo a proxima SEQUENCIA. Depois disso, basta pegar esse valor e colocar no INSERT que você já faz de uma venda nova.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46982/discussion-between-lilloh-and-cantoni).